# Is $\exists a \in A. \forall b \in B \Rightarrow P(a, b)$ equivalent to $\forall c \in B. \exists d \in A \Rightarrow P(c, d)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Given 2 statements:

$$\exists a \in A. \forall b \in B \Rightarrow P(a, b)$$
and
$$\forall c \in B. \exists d \in A \Rightarrow P(d, c)$$

where lowercase letters are elements(or items);
A and B are sets that define the elements; P is a relationship between the two items in the bracket.

Are they equivalent to each other?
And Why?

Comment: How can they be the same if $A, B, C, D$ can be different sets?

Comment: @ureui sorry, my mistake

Comment: Seems like some condition is missing here.

Comment: Do the $\Rightarrow$s stand for anything, or are they just remnants from natural language that can be ignored?

Comment: In general, these two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: @Gae.S. Just remnants from natural language - in English, "Satisfies" or "implies" I think.

Answer (score 2):

No.

It is not true that there exists a woman on Earth (a in A) such that for every man on Earth (b in B), the woman is his mother [P(a,b)].

However, it is true that for every man on Earth (c in B) there exists a woman on Earth (d in A) such that the woman is his mother [P(c,d)].